# Assumptions on memory layout of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

For which categories of types (standard layout, POD, trivial type, alignment constraints...) are the following assumptions valid?

`B` is a subclass of `A`, and `B* b` a pointer to a `B` object.

1. `A* a = b` has the same address as `b`, i.e.

   ```
   static_cast<A*>(b) == reinterpret_cast<A*>(b)
   ```
2. `B bs[n]` is an array of `B` objects.

   ```
   &bs[i] == static_cast<B*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(bs) + i * sizeof(B))
   ```
3. `offsetof` can be used to access data members of `A` and of `B`, from `b`:

   ```
   int i = *static_cast<int*>(
       reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(b) + offsetof(B, m_i));
   ```

EDIT: Changed `void*` to `unsigned char*` for pointer arithmetic (with 1 byte unit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are both standard-layout and `b` points to a most-derived object of class `B`, then the first assertion should be true.

The `offsetof` macro can be used on members of standard-layout types.

The second point of the question is true for any type `B` because that's how arrays are defined.